# TImestamp format in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Query:

```
select date,TO_CHAR(date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:mm:ss')  from user.table  where rownum<10;


02-08-18 05:21:02.301000000 PM  02/08/2018 17:08:02
```

Problem is minutes in above time are different 'mm' loses the precision of minutes and probably providing some garbage value. How do I format dates without losing precision?

Comment: Please explain the downvote..

Comment: Some self-righteous Oracle guru probably never accidentally typed `mm` for minutes instead of `mi` -- I often make this mistake even after years using Oracle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) you have to use `mi` for minutes.  `mm`  is for the month number

```
select date,
       TO_CHAR(date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')  
from user.table 
where rownum<10;
```

Comment: so MM or mm are same ie cases doesnt matter?

Comment: Case doe not matter for format characters that produce numbers, but those that produce characters, such as `Mon` or 'Month` case matters; `Mon` produces the abbreviated name of the month in Mixed case, such as `Jan` and `MON` would produce `JAN`